# willMove(toParent:) Method when removing a view controller child from another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash

I was reading the apple documentation on this specific method, and it says that "If you are implementing your own container view controller, it must call the willMove(toParent:) method of the child view controller before calling the removeFromParent() method, passing in a parent value of nil."

What happens if you don't follow this guide and call removeFromParent() without using willMove(toParent: nil), does this can cause a crash in the app, if so how does that crash represent, what will be the message on the crash?

Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621381-willmove

Comment: AFAIK, there’s no fixed error or specific crash that will result. But they’re very specific that you must do this, so ignore these instructions at your peril.

Comment: yes, i know that adding this is a no brainer, the thing is that i have a crash on an app but i can't get to reproduce the error, and i wanted to know if the error could be from this, the error has very low occurrences, but it is shown as a “Application tried to present modally an active controller” and we are adding the controller and removing the controller via this method, adding as a child, and the removing the, but when removing, the willMove(toParent: nil) is missing.

Comment: I doubt that the failure to call `willMove(toParent: nil)` would cause that error. Usually that error is a result of trying to present modally an instance that is already in the view controller hierarchy. Usually the error will tell you the type of view controller that was presented (which helps narrow down the problem). So look through your code for examples where you programmatically present that the particular view controller referenced in your error and make sure you’re not accidentally presenting an existing instance.

Comment: that's the thing, that controller is not being presented modally in any way, that controller is only presented as a child of the parent controller, with addChild method, but since it can be replaced by a new instance of the same class, i'm curious that the first added child is not being deallocated correctly before adding the second one and that might cause this issue.

Comment: A couple of things: First, that error explicitly says which view controller class was being presented. Have you confirmed that your child view controller class is the one listed there? Second, you say you’ve been unable to reproduce the error. Does your crash log indicate the iOS version that is crashing? Maybe the affected iOS version was less tolerant about misuse of containment API. Third, your symbolicated crash logs should give you meaningful stack trace. What is that telling you?

Comment: FWIW, you know that your release wasn’t doing containment calls correctly, so it seems that you should simply fix that, release it, and see if you get a regression on this error. If your theory is right, then you will have fixed the problem. I’m not convinced this will fix the crash, but the worst case scenario is that you’ve at least fixed one bug, but that the crash is still there and you’ve now eliminated a variable and you’re no worse off than you are now, but have more information.